# Ajax XML HTTP request parameter encoding and decoding

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, url-encoding, urldecode

1. Situation

Client side, in JavaScript,
I prepare a POST parameter like this:

```
param_i_from_form = document.getElementById("param_i_from_form").value;
param_i_for_url   = "param_i=" + encodeURI(param_i_from_form);
```

***[MARKER_1]***

Then I open and send the XML HTTP request:

```
xmlHttpRequest.open("POST", url, true);        
xmlHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = [...]       
xmlHttpRequest.send();
```

Server side, in Java, I retrieve the parameter:

```
HttpServletRequest request
[...]
param_i = ((String[])request.getParameterMap().get("param_i"))[0];
```

***[MARKER_2]***

At ***[MARKER_1]*** `param_i_from_form` has been encoded as expected.

For example: `the ore was 28% copper` was encoded as `the%20ore%20was%2028%25%20copper`

At ***[MARKER_2]*** `param_i` is: `the ore was 28% copper`

2. Question

I am wondering when the decoding took place because I was expecting to get `the%20ore%20was%2028%25%20copper` at ***[MARKER_2]***?

Comment: If you are running your application in Tomcat, see `Connector URIEncoding="UTF-8"` in server.xml

Comment: Yes, I am running my application in Tomcat and I have this URIEncoding="UTF-8" attribute set.